# UnsatisfiedLinkError Starting JVM Via Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have a plain Eclipse installation without much of anything, and a workspace with a Maven (or better yet Tycho) project. Everything worked until I decided to change the JDK (*Preferences* -> *Installed JREs*); now whenever I start a Maven build or the plug-in unit tests I get the following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: java.lang.Class.getClassLoader0()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
<<no stack trace available>>
```

I have restarted Eclipse and tried a different installation, and since I thought the problem was with the JRE, I changed it back to the original one. Still the same error.

The corresponding 64bit JRE works, but sadly the build has an integration test for 32bit (`Cannot load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM`), so that's why I need to get 32bit to work again.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting all the *.metadata* folder of the workspace and setting it up again helped.